# Ability to select either a file or a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, but using this I can only select folder. I want the ability to also select a zip file ( if not a folder)

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a  file"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False 
        .Filters.Clear 
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    GetFile = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Wouldn't the user know ahead of time what type of object they want to select?  Why not give them two buttons and let them choose at that point?

Answer (score 1):

A zip file is a file, not a (windows) folder, so you would have to use:

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show
```

You can't use the same dialog to obtain either a file or folder.

Think of it this way, if you double-click a folder in the dialog, are you selecting this folder or attempting to open it (to select a file)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, there is no way. How about if you double-click, it takes you inside the folder, but if you click only once on a folder or file, and then press the Select button, then it takes that. I had come across an article that it is doable using API functions, but I not able to find it anymore.

Comment: Anything is possible ;). I wouldn't pursue it personally though. You are using a standard MSO dialog (or would be creating something near to it) and getting it to behave in an unexpected way. The end result should still be selecting *either* a file, or a folder. Trying to do both would be both confusing for the user and messy to implement. But.. it's up to you.